# Which function would you use - Javascript

Tags: javascript, coordinates

I'm new to `javascript` and I have the following code:

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
    var text = "";
    var x = 1;
    var y = 1;
    while(x < 9) {
       text += "<br>" + x +"," + y;
       x++;
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
</script>
```

It prints out a list of `coordinates`:

```
1,1
2,1
3,1
4,1
5,1
6,1
7,1
8,1
```

The question is once it gets to 8,1 What would you use to get it to continue to:

```
1,2
2,2
3,2
4,2
5,2
6,2
7,2
8,2
```

then
    1,3
    and so on until it reaches 3,4 (this could be variable) then it stops.

In an ideal world I would be able to get it to go up to a maximum of 8,12.

Comment: You probably need a second loop encapsulating the other loop. Just think about it, should be pretty easy to come up with.

Comment: Nested loops FTW!

Comment: You should mark one of the answers as helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use another while structure for the seconde value.

```js
var text = "",
    x,
    y = 1;

while (y <= 12) {
    x = 1;
    while (x <= 8) {
        text += "<br>" + x + "," + y;
        x++;
    }
    y++;
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Or you could use a [`for` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

> The **`for`** statement creates a loop that consists of three optional expressions, enclosed in parentheses and separated by semicolons, followed by a statement (usually a block statement) to be executed in the loop.

```js
var text = "",
    x,
    y;

for (y = 1; y <= 12; y++) {
    for (x = 1; x <= 8; x++) {
        text += "<br>" + x + "," + y;
    }
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Why would you complicate it like that, instead of simply using the `for` loop?

Comment: @MichałMiszczyszyn, i kept the spirit of the while loop for the answer.

Comment: The spirit of bad practices? 

Comment: no. while is a good choice. you may not like it, but it is a structure which works well.

Comment: Not in this case. The `for` loop is more concise and much cleaner.

Comment: @MichałMiszczyszyn, i have a different view. both works, but op has worked with while.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135518/discussion-between-michal-miszczyszyn-and-nina-scholz).

Comment: This has work really well but I should have added a bit more detail. I'll add a new question. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Write it like this:

```js
var text = "", x,y;
    
for (y=1; y<= 12; y++) {
  for (x=1; x<= 8; x++) {
    text += "<br>" + x + "," + y;
  }
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
 <p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can nest loops. The best solution here is to use two nested `for` loops:

```js
let text = '';
for (let y = 1; y <= 12; ++y) {
    for (let x = 1; x <= 8; ++x) {
        text += "<br>" + x + "," + y;
    }
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<output id="demo"></output>
```

As you can see, it stops at `8,12`, exactly like you wanted :)

You can find more about different [types of loops and iteration on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fun solution. It is not what I would do but for educational purposes, so take it for what it is.

It uses `Array.prototype.reduce` on inner and outer arrays. The accumulated result of the inner array on each iteration gets added to the accumulator of the outer array. The inner reduce is where all the actual data is added. The outer reduce just accumulates the inner results.

It uses some ECMAScript 2015 features also like the spread syntax and arrow functions.

```js
str = [...Array(12)].reduce((s, _, i) =>
        s + [...Array(8)].reduce((ss, _, j) =>
              ss + (j + 1) + ',' + (i + 1) + "\n", ""),
      "");

console.log(str);
```

I used `"\n"` instead of `"<br>"` so that it shows up in console.

Don't actually use this. Its just to show different way. I would use a nested loop in practice.

Have fun!